# Duplicate fingerprint

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I know this question has been asked multiple times but I didn't find appropriate answer to my problem.

I have created two google projects. I am using SHA1 debug key to create OAuth 2.0 client IDs. I have the same SHA1 key for both the projects but my packages are different.

I created first google project for a different package in my android studio to test the SHEET API and now I am creating another google project for a different package in my android studio to test few other things. I don't want to disturb my previous android project and I want it to be functional without changing anything. hence I am creating new package, new google project and new OAuth 2.0 client IDs.

but whenever I am trying to create OAuth 2.0 client ID, it keeps on giving duplicate fingerprint error.

**Duplicate fingerprint
The fingerprint that you specified is already being used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project.**

Can't I have unique combination of SHA1 + package?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to resolve this issue. So I used the web client package created by Google automatically to pass in the application context.